# What is the song playing in Fairy Tail episode 16 when Natsu asks Gray to handle things with Lyon?

Tags: music, fairy-tail

In *Fairy Tail* season 1 episode 16, at around 04:50, there's a song playing when Natsu asks Gray to handle things with Lyon.

What is the title of this song?

Answer (score 1):

The track is Takanashi Yasuharu - Natsu's Magic 2 ~Fire Dragon's Piercing~ (original: ナツの魔法２ ～火竜の劍角～), track 17 on [Fairy Tail Original Soundtrack Vol.2](https://www.discogs.com/%E9%AB%98%E6%A2%A8%E5%BA%B7%E6%B2%BB-Fairy-Tail-Original-Soundtrack-Vol-2/release/4807898)

EDIT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWGWlVTL9ms

Extended (looped) version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxV067vXT1A